# Le sens de « ne pas savoir où se mettre »

Tags: expressions, sens

Je lis le poème [*Les Cloches*](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Les_Cloches_%28Apollinaire%29) d'Apollinaire, et je suis un peu confuse sur le sens de la phrase « Je ne saurai plus où me mettre ». Je pense que je comprends la définition littérale, qui est en anglais *I will no longer know where to put myself*, mais est-ce que on pourrait le traduire aussi comme *I will no longer know what to do with myself* ?

La strophe en question :

> [Ils] Souriront quand je passerai
>   Je ne saurai plus où me mettre
>   Tu seras loin je pleurerai
>   J’en mourrai peut-être

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Ne pas savoir où se mettre* est une expression familière signifiant *être dans l'embarras*

> **Locution verbale**
>
> *ne savoir où se mettre* /nə sa.vwa.ʁ‿u sə mɛtʁ/ intransitif (se conjugue, voir la conjugaison de savoir)
>
> (Familier) Être dans un embarras, une confusion extrême.<sup>[wiktfr](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ne_savoir_o%C3%B9_se_mettre)</sup>

qui se traduit bien par *not knowing what to do with oneself*. Ici il ne faut pas comprendre le sens littéral.

Comment: Merci pour votre réponse. Je voulait vérifier si ma compréhension de la phrase était correcte :)

Comment: *Familier* est contestable…

Comment: @LeVieuxGildas Comme toujours. On peut dire « considérée comme informelle en français standard » si tu préfère.